# openni_tracker using two Kinects problem

Tags: kinect, openni, openi-tracker, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends.

I am new in ROS and I am trying to track the human skeleton by two different Kinects (from different angles and distances).

But I can not run the "openni_tracker" with two different nods like :

- List item rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker image:=/Kinect_1/rgb/image_color
- List item rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker image:=/Kinect_2/rgb/image_color

Just one of them works... and the other stoped by the ROS telling :

- List item [ WARN] [1403525116.319161909]: Shutdown request received.
  [ WARN] [1403525116.319206167]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]

Does any one know how I could run this node two time paralleled in my computer?

Also, in case of the possible answer, the "openni_tracker" publish the output as a tfMessage on "/tf" topic. In case of two nodes working (by two different" camera, what will be the output of this node?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174588/openni_tracker-using-two-kinects-problem./) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if you can run the openni_tracker on 2 kinects, but in this case I think the problem is that the second node you run has the same name as the first, which is then stopped. So I suggest you to make a [launch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) file where you launch 2 nodes with different names and different parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-06-24**:
@Tirjen : Indeed, I tried and worked very well,
Thanks

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-06-24**:
If the problem is solved, please check the answer as correct